# Sharing folder via Dropbox API

Tags: rest, dropbox-api

I know that this https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares can give me a sharing link but I was thinking is there a way to share a folder to a specific person like in the web UI of Dropbox - Share -> invite people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the API doesn't currently provide a way to share a folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with newly-released [version 2 of the Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-sharing-add_folder_member).